# Lambda function only works once

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, express

So I'm new to AWS serverless architecture. I deployed my first lambda function using Claudia. I'm not sure whether I did it correctly. I deployed all the APIs to one lambda function using Claudia. The API endpoints works individually when I test it on Insomnia. But when I use it in my application only one specific API works and the lambda dies. For instance, I used this POST request to post some items and I have a useEffect in my React application which has a get request to retrieve all the items from the database. But once I post the item, nothing is returned. Could anyone help me understand what I'm doing wrong. P.S this is my final year project which is due in a few weeks. So, a quick answer would be appreciated.
Here is a sample code.

```
// Create a new Intake
router.post("/create", async (req, res) => {
  const intake = req.body;
  const { name, intakeCode, intakeYear } = req.body;

  const checkIntake = await Intakes.findOne({
    where: {
      intakeCode: intakeCode,
    },
  });

  if (checkIntake) {
    res.json({ err: `An intake under ${intakeCode} already exists!` });
  } else {
    try {
      await Intakes.create(intake);
      res.json({ msg: `Successfully created ${name} ` });
    } catch (e) {
      if (e.name == "SequelizeDatabaseError") {
        res.json({ err: "Year only accepts integer" });
      } else {
        res.json({ err: e.name });
      }
    }
  }
});

// Find all Intakes
router.get("/findAll", async (req, res) => {
  const listOfIntakes = await Intakes.findAll();
  res.json(listOfIntakes);
});
```

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are trying to build a Lambda function using JavaScript - but have encountered problems. I'm not familiar with Claudia. One suggestion that I have is to follow the official AWS SDK for JavaScript DEV Guide here:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v3/developer-guide/scheduled-events-invoking-lambda-example.html

That content will walk you through how to create a Lambda function using JS.